# Как сделать выполнение с разными переменными?

Tags: python

У меня есть код, который я запускаю через аргументы. "python code.py a b" код ниже

```
import key
import time
import argparse
import sys
import os

a = b = ''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        a = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        b = sys.argv[2]

beta = переменная(key=a, key1=b)

while 0 >= 0:
  if a > 0:
    код
    exit(0)
  else:
    print(a)
```

В общем у меня 10 значений a и b для которых должен выполняться код, я сделал это через батник таким путём:

```
python code.py a b
python code.py a1 b1
python code.py a2 b2
```

Но это не очень удобно, т.к. открывается много окон и нельзя сразу все отслеживать. Как сделать, чтобы итог print(a) отображался в одном окне, но с разными переменными?

Comment: a b - это некоторые внешние значения или просто набор чисел?

Comment: конкретные значения и всегда разные(внешние)

Comment: ну может тогда просто их передать скопом внутри строки `python code.py a2 b2 "1 2 3 4 5" "9 8 7 6 5" и уже внутри скрипта разбить на связки чисел и последовательно обработать

Comment: так числа, всегда одни и теже

Comment: примерно вот так:
```
a=0
b=2
```
выполнение кода
затем
```
a=5
b=0
```
выполнение кода
и т.д.

Comment: ну тем более - просто я про то, что если скормить несколько задач одному скрипту, то и вывод можно сделать в одной консоли как вам удобно

Comment: я не знаю, как это сделать т.к. не знаю, как сделать сразу несколько циклов

Comment: зачем сразу? один за другим

Comment: так мне нужно, чтобы они все одновременно работали

Comment: ну и что - вызываем тогда в несколько потоков (https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/python-technologies/izuchite-parallelizm-s-python/parallelizm-v-python-kratkoe-rukovodstvo), смысл в том, что 1 скрипт получает все данные вначале и потом уже распараллеливает

Answer (score 1):

если не требуется распараллеливать задачи, то можно все выполнить в одном скрипте

1. передать необходимые числа в качестве двух строк
2. записать из строк числа в списки
3. вызвать основную функцию обработки (т.е. то, что делает сейчас скрипт) для всех чисел

т.е. что-то на подобии

```
attr_a = list(map(int, params_a.split()))
attr_b = list(map(int, params_b.split()))

for obj in zip(attr_a, attr_b):
    main_func(obj[0], obj[1]) # то, что сейчас делает скрипт
```

Ну а если нужна параллельная работа, тогда...
https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/python-technologies/izuchite-parallelizm-s-python/parallelizm-v-python-kratkoe-rukovodstvo

основной смысл - 1 скрипт берет на себя ввод начальных данных и вывод конечных, а посередине может параллелить задачи

Comment: а как мне поместить числа в эти переменные?

Comment: у вас же выше написано - вы используете `sys.argv[1]`, т.е. `attr_a = list(map(int, sys.argv[1].split()))`

Comment: туда, можно вставить одно значение, а у меня их 10

Comment: вставляйте как строку - в строку вы можете воткнуть много значений

Comment: вообще разораться не могу

Comment: представьте 1 скрипт которому вы через входной аргумент скармливаете несколько задач - 1 задача - это 2 числа, значит чтобы через 1/2 аргумента передать 1000 числе что надо сделать? просто передать их как строку чисел, а не как числа, а срипт уже распарсит все это в пары чисел и раздаст распараллеленным задачам

Comment: разобрался спасибо за помощь